# Different areas within a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, prototype

One can create a component in React with the following syntax:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChildComponentOne from './ChildComponentOne';
import ChildComponentTwo from './ChildComponentTwo';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      propOne : '',
      propTwo : '',
      propThree : '',
    };

    this.doThis = this.doThis.bind(this);
    this.doThat = this.doThat.bind(this);
  }

  doThis() {
    ...doingThis code
  }

  doThat() {
    ...doingThat code
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponentOne propOne={this.state.propOne} doThis={this.doThis}/>
      <ChildComponentTwo propTwo={this.state.propTwo} propThree={this.state.propThree} doThat={this.doThat}/>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Does React utilize this [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) syntax because they're trying to make a encapsulated and tidy notation for organizing components. And everything else after the constructor method is centric to React.

Or is is possible to write something like this:

```
App.prototype.doThis = function(){};
App.prototype.doThat = function(){};

function App(){
   this.state = {
      propOne : '',
      propTwo : '',
      propThree : '',
    };

   componentDidMount(){...somecode..}

   componentWillUnmount(){...somecode..}

  render(){
        return (
          <ChildComponentOne propOne={this.state.propOne} doThis={this.doThis}/>
          <ChildComponentTwo propTwo={this.state.propTwo} propThree={this.state.propThree} doThat={this.doThat}/>
        );
  }
}
```

I know I am not too far off as one can utilize just a regular function to create a so-called `functional component`.

Guess the question would be how to utilize the life-cycle methods...

Comment: Take a look at [Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Comment: *how to utilize the life-cycle methods* - what exactly do you mean? There's already `render` and it is lifecycle method. You don't need utilize it, that's framework's job.

Comment: @estus Sorry I updated my question. I just mean if I had to use `componentWillUnmount(){}` or `componentDidMount(){}` where would that go if I declared a component using ES5 constructor/prototype version syntax.

Comment: They are supposed to go to `App.prototype`, similarly to `render` in the answer.

Comment: If you wish to use functional components, you might want to look into using hooks.    https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html?no-cache=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 classes are syntactic sugar for function classes. They actually become functions when the application is transpiled to ES5.

React class components are expected to have `render` method and prototypically inherit from `React.Component`, this is how they differ from functional components.

`render` should preferably be prototype method:

```
App.prototype = Object.create(Component.prototype);
App.prototype.render = function () { ... };

function App(props) { ... }
```

Because `this.render = ...` instance method  isn't justified. Also it may expected to be prototype method by some third-party libraries.